# Finding region programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkreversegeocoder

I need to find in what region i am in. For example: New York etc. How could i do this programmatically ?

It is possible to find the UUID, or the iOS version of an individual, but how can we find in what region the person is using the application. I have seen some applications having this, and I need to know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called reverse geocoding. You want to use [MKReverseGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The `MKReverseGeocoder` class provides services for converting a map coordinate (specified as a latitude/longitude pair) into information about that coordinate, such as the country, city, or street.

Comment: Is there a way i could make this work for both iOS 4 and 5. Seems like `MKReverseGeocoder:` doesn't work for iOS 5. and `CLGeocoder` doesn't work for iOS 4.

Comment: No, if you want to support both iOS 4 and 5, you'll have to check the OS version and use `MKReverseGeocoder` or `CLGeocoder` accordingly.